# Create a login form in asp.net without using the textmode='Password' property of the textbox

Tags: html, asp.net

I have to implement a password field in ASP.NET without using the `textmode='password'` property.
When I use the `textmode='Password'`, Firefox shows a security warning each time the page is loaded.

Comment: What is that security warning? Just coz only one browser has issue you should not ignore the compatibility of other 10 browsers.

Comment: Can you try <input type="password" runat="server" id="password" name="password"> ?

Comment: I have resolved the issue by making website run on HTTPS protocol instead of HTTP.